# AJAX подгрузка контента (две проблемы)

Tags: javascript, ajax

Очень нужна помощь (ChatGTP не понимает мою печаль :D).
Делаю аякс переходы, мне нужно, чтобы не изменялся хеадер и футер.
Структура.
header.php - css, js.
footer.php окончание стандартного html.

**Код index.php:**

```
<?php include'include/header.php'?>
  <div id="content">
     text text text
  </div>
<?php include'include/footer.php'?>
```

**AJAX.js:**

```
function loadPageContent(url) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
            // Обновление содержимого страницы
            document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = this.responseText;
            
            // Найти ссылки в обновленном контенте и добавить класс ajax-link
            var updatedLinks = document.querySelectorAll('#content a');
            for (var i = 0; i < updatedLinks.length; i++) {
                updatedLinks[i].classList.add('ajax');
            }
        }
    };
    xhttp.open('GET', url, true);
    xhttp.send();
}

// Обработчик события клика по ссылке
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    // Проверить, было ли кликнуто по ссылке с классом ajax-link
    if (event.target.tagName === 'A' && event.target.classList.contains('ajax')) {
        // Запретить переход по умолчанию
        event.preventDefault();
        
        // Получить URL ссылки
        var url = event.target.getAttribute('href');
        
        // Загрузить содержимое страницы с помощью Ajax
        loadPageContent(url);
        
        // Изменить URL в адресной строке
        window.history.pushState(null, '', url);
    }
});
```

**HTML пример перехода**

```
<a class="ajax" href="/ololo.php">ссылка</a>
```

Переход работает, текст выводит и заменяет первоначальний текст.
Но как вы уже поняли, есть проблеми и я не знаю, какая хуже :(

1. Если понтециальный пользователь начнет своё посещение сайта с условной страницы ololo, то его там ждет просто текст, поскольку **indude** header/footer есть только в index.php. Казалось бы, подключи в ololo.php includы и всё. Нельзя, потому, что при ajax переходе будет дублироваться html тєло со всем барахлом. Второе решение, это просто убрать window.history.pushState(null, '', url); и дело з концом, но что это тогда за сайт, когда нельзя дать ссылку на конкретную страницу? В общем, не знаю как быть.
2. Если перейти на всю ту же ololo.php, а потом обратно на index.php , то  происходит перезагрузка страницы, вместо того, чтобы вернут первоначальный text text text.
   Буду очень благодарен за помощь, подказки, или даже решение, как с логикой построения, так и кодом.

Comment: Полагаю, у вас что-то типа SPA-приложения намечается. Кажется, как раз для этого и придумали разного рода Vue.js, React.js и т.п. И лучше использовать их. А так, ради интереса можете попробовать всё-таки подключать header.php и footer.php на каждой странице, но обернув их в условие типа ```if(empty($_POST)) {include 'include/*.php';}```. При этом сам контент на этих страницах так же пусть будет обёрнут в ```<div id="content"></div>```. В Ajax.js добавить новую переменную ```let data = new FormData(); data.append('action', 'get_content_page');```? метод на **POST**, метод ```send(data)```

Comment: ```<div id="content">``` вынесите в header.php и  закрывающий ```</div>```  - в footer.php. Но всё это только ради интереса, пожалуйста.